# Is it possible to burn (specifically transfer to address(0))a ERC721 token(openZeppelin v4.7 or v4.8) without externally available _burn() function?

Tags: erc-721, burn

If a token does **NOT** have externally available _burn function, and the implementation of openZepplin ERC721.sol for transferFrom() safeTransferFrom() safeTransferFrom("") is

```
function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public virtual override {
        //solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved");

        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-safeTransferFrom}.
     */
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public virtual override {
        safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "");
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-safeTransferFrom}.
     */
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory data
    ) public virtual override {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved");
        _safeTransfer(from, to, tokenId, data);
    }
```

and they all use  `_safeTransfer(from, to, tokenId, data);` or `_transfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)`

```
 function _safeTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory data
    ) internal virtual {
        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
        require(_checkOnERC721Received(from, to, tokenId, data), "ERC721: transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer");
    }
```

and inside of _transfer() is require `require(to != address(0), "ERC721: transfer to the zero address");`

```
function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual {
        require(ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId) == from, "ERC721: transfer from incorrect owner");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC721: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId, 1);

        // Check that tokenId was not transferred by `_beforeTokenTransfer` hook
        require(ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId) == from, "ERC721: transfer from incorrect owner");

        // Clear approvals from the previous owner
        delete _tokenApprovals[tokenId];

        unchecked {
            // `_balances[from]` cannot overflow for the same reason as described in `_burn`:
            // `from`'s balance is the number of token held, which is at least one before the current
            // transfer.
            // `_balances[to]` could overflow in the conditions described in `_mint`. That would require
            // all 2**256 token ids to be minted, which in practice is impossible.
            _balances[from] -= 1;
            _balances[to] += 1;
        }
        _owners[tokenId] = to;

        emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);

        _afterTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId, 1);
    }
```

is it possible in any way or form, to transfer a token to address(0) `0x0` ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can still "burn" them (as in making them unavailable)

Just instead `address(0)` send them to `address(1)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the logic that I'm interested in is that the **_owners** Mapping `mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;` default value is the address(0) and I wanted to know is there a way to change `_owners[tokenId] ` to address(0) so it's would be mistaken with the default  value of the mapping
`function _exists(uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
        return _ownerOf(tokenId) != address(0);
    }`
does it stop **_exists(uint256 tokenId)** and return **False**?

Comment: If tokens are burned "Sent to address(0)" the function _exists() will return false for the burned tokenId.  However, if you just make tokens unavailable by sending them to address(1), the _exists() function will return true. 

You simply can't transfer tokens to address(0) in ERC721 standard if you haven't implemented burn() function.

Answer (score 1):

Common alternative [burn addresses](https://etherscan.io/accounts/label/burn) are the [`dead addresses`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD) or the [`one address`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001).

In general, it is not recommended to burn tokens by sending them to a burning address, as the total supply will not be updated correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the logic that I'm interested in is that the **_owners** Mapping ` mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;` default value is the address(0) and I wanted to know is there a way to change `_owners[tokenId] ` to address(0) so it's would be mistaken with the default  value of the mapping